# java: extends a inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

**jdk version:1.8.0_241**

There is a class extending a inner class. Code as follows:

```java
class WithInner {
    class Inner {

    }
}

public class ExtendInnerClass extends WithInner.Inner {
    ExtendInnerClass(WithInner withInner) {
        withInner.super(); 
    }
}
```

To connect WithInner class's object and Inner class's object, we have to use **super()** method.
But when i decompiled the class file, i find something interesting.

```java
public class ExtendInnerClass extends Inner {
    ExtendInnerClass(WithInner withInner) {
        withInner.getClass();
        super(withInner);
    }
}
```

I find that compiler not only use super() method but also **withInner.getClass()**.

**why he do this?**

Comment: to make sure class WithInner is loaded?

Comment: To check that `withInner` is not `null`. This statement would throw a NullPointerException if `withInner` were `null`.

Answer (score 1):

An inner class object usually need to hold a reference to its outer class object.

Inner class has loaded before outer class without getClass(), it doesn't meet the principle of jvm, so use getclass() to load outer class in jvm before inner one.